# How to filter by the same column twice in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hue

Say I have a column of dates, categories, and values to be summed. I wish to group by the categories and sum over the values such that it satisfies certain condition over a certain set of dates, and another condition over another set of dates.

Something like:

```
 SELECT categories, SUM(values) 
 FROM table 
 group by categories
 having SUM(values) = 0 WHEN dates between w AND x 
 AND having SUM(values) > 10000 WHEN dates between y and z
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
 select categories, sum(values) 
 from table 
 group by categories
 having sum(case when dates between w and x then values else 0 end) = 0 and
        sum(case when dates between y and z then values else 0 end) > 10000 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (`SUM` only values that respect the condition into `IIF` clause):

```
SELECT categories, SUM(values) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY categories
HAVING SUM(IIF(dates BETWEEN w AND x, values, 0)) = 0 
AND SUM(IIF(dates BETWEEN y AND z, values, 0)) > 10000
```